# Using an anchor to open another tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, anchor

I am having trouble trying to figure this out. I want to open a tab from a link to an anchor. Here's what I have. I am using `jquery` 1.8.3. It was working fine but I am unsure what happened.

```
        jQuery(function ($){

        $(".tabContents").hide();
        $(".tabContents:first").show();

        $("#tabContainer ul li a").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var activeTab = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#tabContainer ul li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
            $(".tabContents").hide();
            $(activeTab).fadeIn();
        });
          });
         $('a.tlink').on('click', function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var whereTo = $(this).attr('goto');
            $tabs = $("#tabContainer li");
           $tabs.find('a[href=#' + whereTo + ']').trigger('click');
            //alert(attr('name'));
        //alert( $('#'+whereTo+' a').offset().top );
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#'+whereTo+' a').offset().top
            });
        });
```

here's the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KgaKk/35/).

Thank you.

Comment: If it was working fine, what changed before it broke?

Comment: I don't see a problem with your example.  What's wrong?

Comment: My link is not opening the tab I want it to open. Please see the link I've provided. I have no idea what's went wrong here :-/

Answer (score 0):

in the example you dont have a `goto` in the anchor,

working example, i added the `goto='tab2'` : http://jsfiddle.net/KgaKk/36/

Comment: gah...thank you. I don't know why I didn't think to do that :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd remove the <a name="anchor"> element and set your link's href to "#tab2" (to keep approach consistent) and, instead, remove the "#" from your code to read as follows:

`$tabs.find('a[href=' + whereTo + ']').trigger('click');`

...otherwise, you'll have a double "#" in your selector string.

Comment: thank you. this approach does not seem to work for me [example](http://jsfiddle.net/cfpxj/1/) http://jsfiddle.net/cfpxj/1 would you mind showing me what you mean?